# CodeSandbox and Angular Material 13

Tags: angular, angular-material, codesandbox

I'm trying to get an Angular Material instance working with the latest (13.x) version, using CodeSandbox (and by extension the CLI).  I am receiving the dreaded, "Could not find angular material Core Theme" error.  Note that I have tried importing via the usual routes

> **angular-cli.json:**
> `"styles": ["./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"],`

> **styles.css:**
>
> ```
> @import "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";
> @import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css";
> ```

Note that the first approach doesn't "fail", but doesn't help at all with theming.  The second approach yields a different error:

> `postcss-import: /src/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css:1:1: Unknown word`

Sample project is at https://codesandbox.io/s/idle-test-r3rqp3.  Any tips or pointers are appreciated.

Joe Allan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The config file should be called `angular.json` in angular 13. Here's a stackblitz with angular 13 and material set up: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-w8wwx5?file=angular.json

and here's the config file:

```json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "demo": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/demo",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "demo:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "demo:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "demo:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "styles.css",
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": ["src/favicon.ico", "src/assets"]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": ["src/tsconfig.app.json", "src/tsconfig.spec.json"],
            "exclude": ["**/node_modules/**"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "demo"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips!  I've updated the sample/demo app, and although everything now seems set up according to what you've provided, and I'm not seeing any "failures", the Themes still aren't initializing. :(

https://codesandbox.io/s/idle-test-r3rqp3 updated per your recommendation.

Comment: Well I copied the whole project from stackblitz over to code sandbox, it works in stackblitz but not in sandbox. So I'd say it's a bug in the site.

Comment: Yeah, seems that way to me as well.  Was thinking maybe I did something wrong, coz Angular can get a bit obtuse about errors.  Thanks for the help!  I ended up building the prototype with StackBlitz and it's working great!